# On a paper of Formanek about $PGL_4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, invariant-theory

In his paper "[The center of the ring of 4 × 4 generic matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(80)90184-2)" (Journal of Algebra, 1980) Formanek shows that, if $V$ is the representation of $PGL_4$ given by simultaneous conjugation of pairs of matrices, then $V/PGL_4$ is rational. Let $\mathbb{G}_m^4$ have coordinates $a_i$, and let $T\subseteq \mathbb{G}_m^4$ be the subtorus given by $a_1a_2a_3a_4=1$. Let $S_4$ act on $\mathbb{G}_m^4$ via the permutation$\otimes$sign representation. Formanek reduces the original problem to showing that $T/S_4$ is rational. The proof then proceeds by explicitly finding a transcendence basis for $k(T)^{S_4}$, which is expressible in a rather complicated way in terms of the $a_i$.

Since $40$ years have now passed, I was wondering if nicer/shorter proofs now exist. It would be nice if the last computation of the invariants could be skipped, maybe reducing to a different torus?

Comment: I can say very little about this problem, but in http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/~traedschelders/subs/notes/rationality.pdf the authors give a nicer / shorter proof for the $3\times 3$ case. Maybe this is of some help.